# How to redirect from https://abc.def.com to https://uvw.xyz.com?

Tags: apache

I need to redirect from https://abc.def.com to https://uvw.xyz.com

I have tried with the following Apache redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http

RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.def\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://uvw.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^uvw\.xyz\.com$

RewriteRule  ^.*$ - [F]
```

Instead of redirecting to the https, it is getting redirected to http. I also have a redirection rule for http://uvw.xyz.com to redirect to https://uvw.xyz.com so  that if anybody tried to access the url insecurely it redirects to the secure network.

I have a use case to load this in an iframe under another application which is on https. I am getting the following error while trying to open the page with the iframe.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://someapplication.com/someaction'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://uvw.xyz.com/someotheraction'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

Please help me with the correct redirection  rule

I am on Apache/2.2.31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was very simple. We just changed the redirect URL to https://uvw.xyz.com/ on the fifth line of the original redirection rule that we wrote

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://uvw.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also my browser cached the results from my previous rule and it was always going to the http, so I just cleared my browser cache and it started redirecting properly.